# How to handle API errors in Android app using Facebook 3.0 SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication

I've developed an Android app which uses Facebook SDK 3.0. On developers.facebook.com its showing a lot of API errors most common ones are :

> auth.androidauthorizeapp
>
> auth.extendssoaccesstoken

Can someone tell me what I can do to fix these errors ? Your help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: have you successfully created facebook app and define in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yep I have a properly working app but on fb developer site its showing
a lots of API error of above mentioned kinds, so some users have complaints about its functioning.

Answer (score 2):

From the two errors you've provided, I can't come up with much. However, I wanted to make sure you haven't overlooked the answer.

My suggestion to you is to look at the page below and see if any of the situations given at the link below may apply to your scenario:

[See this page on the Facebook Developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#errors)

Here is an excerpt regarding the second error:

> "Facebook doesn't notify you that a previously issued access token has become invalid. Unless you have persisted the expiry time passed to your App along with the access token, your app may only learn that a given token has become invalid is when you attempt to make a request to the API."